# Google App Engine short URL tracking with Google Analytics

Tags: google-app-engine, google-analytics, shortcode, short-url

My website generates some short URLs when users share a link (ex: http://futureo.us/l/ixjF).

These short URLs redirect the user to the original content I'm linking to. Before redirecting, the app renders a page that contains only Google Analytics javascript code.

Currently my handler code looks like this:

```
class PostHandler(handler.Handler):
def get(self, code):
    #strip URL shortcode
    code = code.strip('/')
    #grab URL based on shortcode
    url = scripts.urlshort.getURL(code)
    if url:
        self.render('tracking.html')
        self.redirect(str(url))
    else:
        self.write('Code not FOUND.')
```

This solution isn't working. GA is not registering pageviews to these short links. I would alo like to see who where the referrers to these short-links.

Any ideas how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you're adding an HTML tracking code, in a response that has HTTP redirection. Probably the HTTP redirection is processed earlier than the HTML, if the latter is evaluated at all.

Seems to me that the best solution would be to track the redirects on the server side rather than on the client side. As these are redirects anyway, you don't need to track client-only data such as time spent on page, page events etc. Tracking the redirect would be most accurate and simpler if done in the python code. (I don't know, though, of a way to use the google analytics tools for tracking these; for my uses I just track the redirects in an NDB model).

Another solution, which might be slower on the user experience, is to avoid using HTTP redirect (`self.redirect`) and instead put a javascript client-side redirect which will be evaluated after the tracking code.

```
window.location = "{{url}}";
```

Comment: Thank you Onon15.
I will wait for other opinions before closing this question and accepting your answer. There may be more ways to solve this.

Comment: Minor suggestion: setting window.location directly might cause redirection before GA has loaded and/or recorded analytics data. The following code makes sure GA has been loaded, and waits 100ms to give time for the tracking data to be sent: `_gaq.push([function(){setTimeout(function(){window.location = "{{url}}";}, 100)}]);`.

Comment: @mike , I'm not sure how I should implement this. 

Should I paste that line of code inside the GA javascript script? After `_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X]);` and `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);`?

I tried doing that but the redirect isn't working. It loads the page but nothing happens after. Sorry, I'm a beginner with javascript.

Comment: Alright guys, got it working! Thanks! 

@mike, I just had to remove the brackets after `_gaq.push(` to get your code to work. Thanks!

Comment: @GianCarloMartinelli -- Good catch, there shouldn't have been brackets. And I'd put it after the `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);`